# Where can I get my website critiqued

Tags: website-design

As a fairly new web designer to the industry, I am looking to improve my designs and usability of my websites. Where can I submit my website to get peer-reviewed or professionally critiqued, preferably for free?

Comment: "professionally critiqued, preferably for free" - If you're willing to build a free website in trade I'm sure someone will take you up on the offer.

Comment: @danlefree Who? Where can I even get in touch with someone? If they  can professionally critique my site, why would they need me to design them a site? My best option is a site where I can critique a site and then someone can critique me back. Or somewhere where I can submit my site and people can simply make comments or suggestions.

Comment: Chaim this is something I've been seeking lately as well.  I thought UX would be the place, but my post got shot down in minutes.   Did you ever find a site or service?  Devshed has a critique forum, but their password reminder is broken and new accounts are not allowed to post in the critique forum.

Answer (score 3):

The [Sitepoint forums allow website review requests](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/forumdisplay.php?273-Content-Reviews). You have to review three other sites first and then your site is made avaiable for others to critique.

Comment: Thanks, although I'm having a little trouble finding three sites to review that haven't already been closed by the forum moderators.

Comment: URL changed in the meantime: http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/forumdisplay.php?f=12

Comment: Good luck getting a review as a new member.

Answer (score -2):

The http://www.sitefeedbacks.com/ site helps you to **get reviews on your site**. It's similar to SitePoint, but it's not a forum and it's specialized on free site reviews.

The idea is: **make 2 reviews** on other sites and then **post your site** to be reviewed by others.

Hope it will help.